# Boost ASIO as an event loop with boost lockfree queue for socket write

Tags: multithreading, boost, c++14, boost-asio, lock-free

I am using boost ASIO for a TCP client. for the most part the ASIO is a glorified event loop for read and write. There is actually only one client managed by the ASIO.

The architecture is like this - 
The TCP server streams continuous messages. The Client will read the messages, process it and ack back with proper code.

My code runs in client side. There is one thread running io_service. The io_service thread reads messages and distributes it to N number of worker threads using a boost lockfree SPSC queue. The workers after processing posts the replies to the io_service thread.

most important concern for me is the rate of read and write. So I am using synchronous reads and writes.

Read Code:

```
 void read ()
 {

     if (_connected && !_readInProgress) {
         _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
                 make_boost_alloc_handler(_readAllocator,
                     [self = shared_from_this(), this] (ErrorType err, unsigned a)
                     {
                          connection()->handleRead(err);
                          _readInProgress = false;

                          if (err) disconnect();
                          else asyncRead();

                     });
         _readInProgress = true;
     }
 }
```

Basically I use read_some with nullbuffer() and then directly use Unix system calls to read the messages. The read give N number of messages which are enqueued to threads in a loop.

I want use the boost SPSC queue in the reverse direction for writes to the socket from workers.

Write:

```
// Get the queue to post writes
 auto getWriteQ ()
 {
     static thread_local auto q = 
         std::make_shared< LFQType >(_epoch);
     return q;
 }
```

So each thread gets a thread-local Q using getWriteQ. The writes to the queue looks like this:

```
void write (Buf& buf) override
 {
     auto q = getWriteQ();

     while (!q->enqueue(buf) && _connected);

     if (!_connected) return;

      _ioService.post( [self = shared_from_this(), this, q]() 
      {
           writeHelper(q); });
      }
}
```

Now this is inefficent, as we do a ioservice post for each write. The write handler at a time actually writes upto 32 messages in a single system-call using sendmmsg()

So I am looking for help with 2 things:

- Is the design any good?
- Any fool proof way to minimize the no. of posts. I was thinking of keep an atomic enqueue count. The worker thread will do this -
  the writing thread does this - (Pseudo code)

  bool post = false;

  if(enqueue_count == 0)  post = true

  // enqueue the message

  ++enqueue_count

  if(post)
      // post the queue event

The io-service thread does this -

```
enqueue_count -= num_processed;
if (enqueue_count) 
// repost the queue for further processing
```

Would this work if the enqueue_count is atomic ?

Comment: Second half of the question is not clear at all. Do you want to batch post calls ? What is the inefficiency with the post operation that you are facing ? Too many post adding to latency in processing ? Would calling `dispatch` instead make any difference in your case ?

Comment: I don't think dispatch makes a difference as post (the write() function above) is not called from thread running ioservice. It's called from the worker thread.

Comment: The inefficiency is due to too many posts. The messages to write, as  I mentioned, is added to a lockfree queue. And the write handler (write helper()) writes multiple messages to socket. So we don't need post per message. For eg. So if we add a message to the queue and the writeHelper() has not run since last time it a message was added to queue. We don't have to repost.